# Chemokines vs Chemoattractants

Tags: cell-biology, immunology

What differentiates chemokines from chemoattractants? They both are grouped by their chemotaxic function, but what features separate them.

What are examples of other chemoattractants that are not chemokines? Or examples that are not even proteins at all?

Comment: What research have you done on this subject? Simply reading the respective Wikipedia pages should tell you the difference (hint: read about `chemotaxis` and `chemokine`).

Comment: See also: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8139/what-is-the-distinction-between-chemokines-cytokines-interferons-and-interleuk

Comment: @MattDMo I am not asking about chemotaxis vs chemokines or chemokines vs cytokines. Strictly the difference between two groups of chemotaxia inducing molecules. The link provided does not help answer this question. I will reword my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Did you read both of the suggested Wikipedia articles entirely? The `chemotaxis` article includes information on chemoattractants, as it doesn't have its own page. I know the question I linked doesn't completely address your question, which is why I didn't mark it as a duplicate. It was merely intended to provide some additional information.

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, the wikipedia article on chemtaxis mentioned chemokines once as a subgroup of chemoattractants, however there was no explanation on why this was. The article on chemokines also did not offer an explanation on my question.

Comment: And there is your answer. `Chemoattractant` is a general term to describe all molecules/atoms/ions, organic and inorganic, that induce cell motility. `Chemokines` are one type of chemoattractant, there are a number of others as well.

Comment: @MattDMo Ok thank you for helping me find this answer. I will need to improve my questions in the future. I was looking for what separates chemokines out from chemoattractants, which appears to be their four cysteine residues and approximate size of 8-10 kilodaltons. My confusion was from my professor's definition of chemokines as any protein that will induce chemotaxis.